# Python Selenium accessing multilevel HTML

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can i access the multilevel html file using python selenium module. Sample html file is  :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#">
    <head>
        <body style="background: rgb(26, 26, 26)" class="remodal_lock remodal_active">
        <iframe id="ifrBmAuthApi" class="black-bg">
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
                <head>
                </head>
                <body>  
                <div class="ascendon">
                    <div id="accountManagementDiv" class="container-fluid">
                        <form id="SAMLPOST" method="POST">
                            <div class="validation-summary" cdvalidate="Email"></div>
                            <input id="Email-input" class="form-control stacked-input err" data-prop="Email" maxlength="50" required="" placeholder="Email" type="email">
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
    </iframe>   
    </body>
</head>
```

I wanted to access the inner html file-id : "Email-input"

I tried following scenario to directly access the id="Email-input" and class="form-control stacked-input err" getting failed.

e.g. : >>> print driver.find_element_by_id("Email-input").is_displayed()

False

Answer (score 2):

I solved it using switch_to.frame(id of the frame)

```
browser.switch_to.frame("ifrBmAuthApi")
```

Browser is the variable of the Webdriver